# MYSQL, Have AE be equal to Æ on search

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to search for "ae" and have both "ae" and "Æ" as result. I just can't figure out how to do it.

I tried collating as utf8_german2_ci and utf8_general_ci. Both should be able to do just what I want from what I read. But it's just not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details on what you have tried, so at least the table definition including its collations, and the query you tried including any collations. Also, if you did this from PHP, the problem could be there. Maybe you try to store some ANSI representaton of this character into a UTF-8 string or so.

Comment: I tried a host of different collations, both utf8 and latin. Both from PHP and setting the column to that collation. Finally I found that those two I listed should work. (source http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)

Currently my column is set to utf8_german2_ci. 
If I use
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Kaartnaam FROM Kaarten WHERE Kaartnaam LIKE '%ae%' COLLATE utf8_german2_ci ");
It only results the AE results. If I remove the COLLATE (I think it's redundant if the DB is set to the same?), it also only shows AE results.

Comment: Does "select hex('Æ'),hex(column_name) from Kaarten;" show that the character's value is C386? Does "select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'Kaarten'; show that the column's collation is utf8_german2_ci?

Comment: Just tried. Yes to both.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment ("Just tried. Yes to both."), I gather that there's nothing wrong with your database or connection. Your only problem is the LIKE. LIKE does a "per-character" comparison, and the MySQL manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html has an illustration very similar to your case (using "SELECT 'ä' LIKE 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;"). So you're looking at expected behaviour, but can say "select s1, hex(s1) from tj where s1 like '%ae%' or s1 like '%æ%';".

Comment: Thanks for the response. At least I know I have to find a workaround on the "like".

Your example is easy enough, but need to figure out how to incorporate something like that into a search script where people can search for anything.

I guess if/else would work, but seems wrong.